# low bandwith usage on golang exec.Command("").Run()

Tags: go, youtube-dl

I am building a golang app which uses youtube-dl to download some files from mixcloud.
I recognized that when I execute `youtube-dl https://www.mixcloud.com/FatboySlim/` in my terminal I receive download speeds with an average of 10 MiB/s.

When I execute the same command in golang I only receive download speeds with an average of 2 MiB/s.

Is there any reason why it is so slow? Any idea how to fix it?

Reproduce as follows:

In Bash/Shell

```sh
bash youtube-dl https://www.mixcloud.com/FatboySlim/
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("youtube-dl", "https://www.mixcloud.com/FatboySlim/")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try "youtube-dl -q" - the script may be blocking on output, which contains a progress bar and might be slower with the extra levels of redirection / processing.

Comment: @BadZen seems like you're right!
I have now an average of 8-9 MiB/s.
I would be interested in the logs of youtube-dl, but the trade-off with the low bandwith usage is not worth seeing the logs.

Comment: check the options of the program, it provides a `--no-progress` flag. https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#options Besides,i would buffer the writes to standards IOs of the program.